# choice command in Batch not working

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

Okay, so I'm having some trouble using errorlevel and the choice command, and frankly I have no idea what's going on.

I've been using this code:

```
:CACD  
set stage=CACD  
echo.  
echo Make a choice  
echo.  
echo 1)  
echo 2)    
echo 3)  
echo.  
choice /c 7034 /n  
if %errorlevel% == "3" goto choice3  
if %errorlevel% == "2" goto se2  
if %errorlevel% == "1" goto choice1  
goto CACD  

:choice3  
echo you chose 3  
pause  
goto CACD  

:se2  
echo you chose 2  
pause  
goto CACD  

:choice1  
echo you chose 1  
goto CACD
```

Whenever I enter 1, nothing happens. Same thing with 2. But whenever I enter 3, it works? Can anyone help?

Comment: Your Choice command is only going to accept four characters as input, `7`, `0`, `3` & `4`. I think you may want to change it to `CHOICE /C 123 /N`

Comment: Have you ever thought of reading the documentation of the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), by typing `choice /?` into a new command prompt window?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Compo! It worked! I wasn't sure what the number was for, I thought it was a variable or something like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Compo - Propose your comment as an answer.

Comment: Seems to me that it shouldn't work as written  even with the `7034` switched to `123`... Odd that OP claims it did..??

Comment: I agrre with Magoo, you can't succesfully compare with one argument quoted the other not - they'll always be different.

Answer (score 1):

Since choice limits your input, errorlevel can only be one of 1,2,3,255

You can omit all the if commands if you append the errorlevel to your goto label:
and name all the labels accordingly.

```
@Echo off
:CACD  
set stage=CACD  
echo.  
echo Make a choice  
echo.  
echo 1)  
echo 2)    
echo 3)  
echo.  
choice /c 123 /n  
goto choice%errorlevel%
:Choice255
Echo an error occured with your choice
goto :Eof  

:choice3  
echo you chose 3  
pause  
goto CACD  

:choice2  
echo you chose 2  
pause  
goto CACD  

:choice1  
echo you chose 1  
goto CACD
```